# How to properly reference javascript files in to asp.net master page?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I am getting problem in referencing Javascript file.

My all js files reside in my js folder:`MyProject/Js/*.js`

Now on my master page i am refering my file like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Error showing in console**:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'.
```

On searching i have found that this issue comes due to inappropriate referencing of js files so i have resolve this error by doing this:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This above solution works when my .aspx page would be like this:

`MyProject/Admin/Abc.aspx  //This will work`

But problem will occur when any of my .aspx page would be like such:

```
MyProject/Admin/Subfolder/Abc.aspx // This will not work
```

My Abc.aspx page contains **master page** but now in this case this will not load my js files due to `../`

So can anybody tell me whats the correct way to reference js files which will work in both the cases??

**Note**:I am referencing all js files in to my master page and my master page is in:

```
MyProject/MasterPage.Master
```

Comment: What about put them into the bundle? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx

Comment: Will this above solution would work in my both the scenarios??

Comment: Actually, the problem of `../` could be solved by `~/` which is referred to the root folder. In ASP.NET, we can use bundle to reduce the loading time. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Comment: and... Yes, the above solution would work in both scenarios.

Comment: Drag and drop one js file in  your master file, you will get the a prepared script tag.

Comment: @Arshad:i have already done that but getting path like this:js/jquery-1.9.1.js

Answer (score 2):

I think you can give a try:

1) Use [Bundling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx) to [reduce the loading time](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) (Your script will be shorter as well)

2) Use `~/` instead of `../` to make your script/code work even if you relocate the pages.

**You can easily find the scripts and codes of jquery bundle if you create a new  ASP.NET application in Visual Studio.**